# crawling sites in python with POSTing forms - which tool to use

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

There's a website which has a form. I would like to automate a process that I enter some values to the form and check the results. I would like to scan quite a lot of form combinations (that's why I don't want to do this manually). Unfortunately, I was unable to automate it using cURL because of some heavy cookie usage.

I thought that maybe I can use real browsers to do some automation for me? I was thinking of phantomjs and selenium (haven't used selenium so far). Does selenium run a real browser? This would be good, since a real browser would handle all the cookie stuff.

In short: I would have a bunch of python dictionaries that would be used to fill the website form. After filling the form, I want to scan HTML to retrieve the result. Afterwards, I'll summarize everything (this step will be easy). Does selenium suit my needs? Can you recommend something better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes selenium is a browser emulator it opens an actual browser window when you run it

phantom-js is a headless web kit for selenium and it will run the browser in the background without showing the actual browser window

if you cant use, urllib, requests or mechanize then yes your best shot is using selenium

for the HTML parsing I recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) its really easy to use and will get all the info you need

Comment: There are some tools which sit on top of Selenium to make it easier to use, such as http://splinter.cobrateam.info/

The idea is that you describe what you want to achieve, similar to how a human would describe it, and Splinter tries to accommodate you, handle AJAX and delays and retries and such.

Full Disclosure:  I gave a talk on Splinter at PyCon-AU so I might be biased:P  (http://pyvideo.org/video/2237/web-testing-for-ninjas-with-splinter)